# Bootstrap social buttons

Tags: javascript, python, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm using [social buttons for twitter bootstrap 2](http://noizwaves.github.io/bootstrap-social-buttons/). For some reason, the Facebook "f" logo in the button is not showing up. Here is my front end code:

```
{% include "meddy1/header.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href="../../static/meddy1/css/social-buttons-3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../bootstrap-social-gh-pages/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- CSS links -->
    <link href="{% static "meddy1/css/login-signup.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{% static "meddy1/css/login-signup-responsive.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- End CSS links -->


 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <!-- Log In -->
        <div class="login">
          <h1> SIGN UP </h1>

  {% if user.is_authenticated and not user.is_superuser %}
      <h3>Hi {{ user.first_name }}. Thanks for loggin in!</h3> 
  {% else %}
      <buttton class="btn btn-facebook"><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ index }}" class="fa fa-facebook"> | Signup with Facebook</a></buttton>
  {% endif %}

  <h4> OR </h4>

  <form action="" method="post" id="user_uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
   {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

   <p class="alert">By Clicking “Sign Up” below, you are agreeing to the Meddy <a href="/terms">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="ss-submit">SIGN UP</button>
    <form></form>

    <button class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | Connect with Facebook</button>




</div>
        <!-- End Log In -->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content -->


  </body>
</html>

{% include "meddy1/footer.html" %}
```

Am I missing a link to any crucial file? Can't figure out why the Facebook logo isn't showing up. My webapp is in Django.

Comment: Post the HTML output please. Also providing an online example could be helpful.

Comment: This may explain it, a bit from the Font-Awesome website     Warning!
Apparently, Adblock Plus can remove Font Awesome brand icons with their "Remove Social Media Buttons" setting. We will not use hacks to force them to display. Please report an issue with Adblock Plus if you believe this to be an error. To work around this, you'll need to modify the social icon class names.    TRY using a different icon to see if that might be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add this line:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Well, then something else is wrong, since you earlier added a reference to font -awesome (from your project folder).   There is no need to load two copies of the CSS, so I suspect your font awesome font folder is not set up properly on your local machine

Comment: so I inspected my font-awesome.min.css and it's looks really different from the one at maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com

Comment: The one you are using from maxcdn is the minimized CSS file (extra whitespace removed to make it load faster),   The one in your web page is the normal version, with whitespace kept for readability and development

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the i tag inside the button tag:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

Which would then look like this for you:

```
<buttton class="btn btn-facebook"><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ index }}" class="fa fa-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | Signup with Facebook</a></buttton>
```